# How does Yahoo! Image Search load its images?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, yahoo-search

I just recently noticed that when you click an image on Yahoo! Image Search it first shows a low resolution image which then gradually turns into a high resolution image.

**Example:**
[Yahoo! Image Search](http://images.search.yahoo.com/images/view;_ylt=A0PDoTD9ZHROSHIA5aqJzbkF;_ylu=X3oDMTBlMTQ4cGxyBHNlYwNzcgRzbGsDaW1n?back=http://images.search.yahoo.com/search/images?p=great%2bbarrier%2breef&n=30&ei=utf-8&y=Search&b=1&tab=organic&w=1024&h=768&imgurl=www.tws3d.com/wallpapers/great-barrier-reef-marine-park-queensland-australia-1024x768.jpg&rurl=http://www.tws3d.com/view/great-barrier-reef-marine-park-queensland-australia-1024x768&size=347.7%20KB&name=Description%3a%20Great%20Barrier%20Reef%20Marine%20Park,%20Queensland%20...&p=great%20barrier%20reef&oid=8bfe6b18934b5d247b8a48d5460a9521&fr2=&fr=&tt=Description%3a%20Great%20Barrier%20Reef%20Marine%20Park,%20Queensland%20...&b=0&ni=30&no=0&tab=organic&sigr=12m8g6s24&sigb=138d1jnpj&sigi=12pqc4ak9&.crumb=w3HTeJm6SJj)

When you click the link above and click through all the images you notice that they're always showing a low resolution image first. Why are they doing it? Does the website appear to be loading faster to the user if they're doing it this way?

Also, could someone please point me into the direction on how this is actually done (preferably by using JQuery, in the case that they're using JavaScript to do it)?

Comment: I believe PNG has such support, but I doubt they use it here.

Comment: That's an [interlaced PNG](http://nuwen.net/png.html), but is not what's going on here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're using a cache of thumbnails from this URL

```
http://ts1.mm.bing.net/images/thumbnail.aspx?q=NUM&id=HASH
```

where `HASH` and `NUM` are (somehow) references to a particular thumbnail.

For example, `NUM = 1148286928700` and `HASH = d2f4bbf91a853cefbc18794b6eb9ecdd` are a reference to [this thumbnail](http://ts1.mm.bing.net/images/thumbnail.aspx?q=1148286928700&id=d2f4bbf91a853cefbc18794b6eb9ecdd).

Of course, thumbnails are smaller in file size than bigger images, so Yahoo! loads from a cache of thumbnails first to give the user a glimpse of what the image is, and loads the full size image in the background.

I suspect the technique they use is load the image in to a hidden `img` tag, and then bind to the `load` event of that image tag to a function which replaces the thumbnail `src` with the full size image `src`. Hence, when the (hidden) full size image is loaded, it replaces the thumbnail image we see on page load.

Let's assume the thumbnail image is loaded in to an `img` tag with an ID of `main_image`, and our full size image is loading (in the background) in a hidden `img` tag with an ID of `secondary_image`. Then we bind to the `load` event of `#secondary_image`, and replace the `src` of `#main_image` on load:

```
$('#secondary_image').load(function() {
  // on big image load, replace the src of the thumbnail image
  $('#main_image').attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));
}
```

Then when the user wishes to view another image, we replace the `src` of `#main_image` with a different cached thumbnail, replace the `src` of `#secondary_image` with the large image, and bind the `load` event again (so ideally you'd create a function with the above code, and call this function whenever you changed the `#secondary_image` `src`.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot for that detailed information, Alex! Appreciate it. Just one more thing, wouldn't it have to be `$('#main_image').attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));`?

Answer (score 1):

All they are doing is showing [a thumbnail](http://ts2.mm.bing.net/images/thumbnail.aspx?q=1186509761557&id=cf064514054542be1945ef73c0701c85) first, then waiting a bit (to save bandwidth for you and real site) then loading [the real image](http://www.universetoday.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/03/Great-Barrier-Reef.jpg). To do that, they are probably just changing the src attribute on the image, or adding another image on top.

Interesting to note that the thumbs are provided by Bing.

Comment: Thanks, Rich! And isn't it because Yahoo is using Bing's search engine?